# How to access the return of Module.nesting outside of the module definition

Tags: ruby, methods, module, namespaces, constants

When using the Module.nesting method, I can return a list of nested Modules from the point of call. The only examples I saw in documentation and elsewhere show the method call being placed and run from within the nested module definition:

```
module M1
  module M2
    Module.nesting #=> [M1::M2, M1]
  end
end
```

In the following example:

```
module A
  module B; end
  module C
    module D
      # I want to access the name-space chain from this point
    end
  end
end

# But how can I reference it from our here?
# A::C::D .... ?
```

is there any way to check the name-space chain within the module once it has been defined?

The only examples I can see create a variable within the definition to hold the resulting call to be referenced again outside of the definition:

```
module A
  module B; end
  module C
    module D
      $chain = Module.nesting
    end
  end
end

p $chain 
#=> [A::C::D, A::C, A]
```

Is there a method to looking this name-spacing chain up, without creating a variable in the definition to be referenced later?

Comment: How would this information be useful outside of that context? How would it differ from what you'd get by splitting on `::` on the module name?

Comment: Honestly this question was purely from a point of curiosity. I don't know if I had a specific use case in mind. Just wondering if that kind of thing were possible!

Comment: Nothing wrong with an academic inquiry to promote understanding. Just asking because there might be another, easier way to solve the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, the way to "remember" the value of an expression is to assign that value to a variable.

Also, the value of a module definition is the value of the last expression that was evaluated inside the body.

If you put the two together, you get something like this:

```rb
chain = module A
  module B; end
  module C
    module D
      Module.nesting
    end
  end
end

p chain 
# [A::C::D, A::C, A]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following nested modules mentioned in the question.

```
module A
  module B; end
  module C
    module D
      Module.nesting
    end
  end
end
  #=> [A::C::D, A::C, A]
```

Now try this:

```
module A::C::D
  Module.nesting
end
  #=> [A::C::D]
```

[Module::nesting](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-c-nesting) resolves the nesting of modules *lexicographically*, meaning that modules are ordered by their point of inclusion, beginning at `A::C::D` and working outward. `Module::nesting` does not "remember" the nesting from where the module was defined; it merely examines the code locally. This is in contrast to subclassing.

Perhaps you can obtain the information you need by using the method [ObjectSpace::each_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object).

```
outer_module = A
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).select { |m| m.to_s.match?(/\A#{outer_module}::/) }
  #=> [A::B, A::C::D, A::C]
```